# How I can remove this white spaces ? (html, css)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm beginner in web development and I don't understand why there is white space here (check screen capture), I would remove them...
PS:I use electron framework to make an desktop app

[image]

```css
* {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#Icon {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.Minimize {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.Close {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

#Triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #20272F;
  margin: auto;
}

#Titre {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img id="Icon" src="Images/icon.png">

  <input type="image" class="Minimize" src="Images/minimize_window_96px.png"></input>
  <input type="image" class="Close" src="Images/close_window_96px.png"></input>
</header>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="Titre">Triangle des equations</h1>
  <div id="Triangle"></div>
  <div id="PartiEquation"></div>
  <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You could start by writing valid HTML. A `<header>` has to be the header of *something* in the `<body>` and the `<input>` element has no end tag. https://validator.nu would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks ! It's helpfull !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset browser margin by use :

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box; }
```

Comment: It's perfect Thanks, the most simple answer ! I just have another little question how i can also remove the white spaces in the inputs(buttons) and in the picture? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

> Try This...

```css
* {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin:0;

}

#Icon {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.Minimize {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.Close {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

#Triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #20272F;
  margin: auto;
}

#Titre {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img id="Icon" src="Images/icon.png">

  <input type="image" class="Minimize" src="Images/minimize_window_96px.png"></input>
  <input type="image" class="Close" src="Images/close_window_96px.png"></input>
</header>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="Titre">Triangle des equations</h1>
  <div id="Triangle"></div>
  <div id="PartiEquation"></div>
  <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! That works ! I just have another little question how i can also remove the white spaces in the inputs(buttons) and in the picture? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Every element has certain rules applied by default by browsers. Try using a css reset script in order to "equalize" them.

This one for example.
https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

My strong advice is to use:

```
header img,
header input {
  float: left;
}
```

This will fix the box model problems and you will avoid generic selector like "*" which has performance implications!